# Execute Thread 2 only after Thread 1 finishes

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Would any of the following codes snippets give a guarantee that pool1 will start only after the pool finished its execution?

**Snippet 1**

```
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    for (FObject action : list) {
        if (action instanceof FObject) {    
            Runnable run = new ImageProcessRunnable(action);
            pool.execute(run);
        }
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    if (pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        pool.shutdownNow();
    }           
    ExecutorService pool1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    synchronized (ImageHelper.getFilePaths()) {
        for (String file :ImageHelper.getFilePaths()) {
            pool1.execute(() -> {
                UploadFileAsAppUser.uploadFileAsBoxAppUser(file, boxLocation);
            });
        }
    }

    pool1.shutdown();
    if (pool1.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        pool1.shutdownNow();
    }
```

**Snippet 2**

```
    for (FObject action : list) {
        if (action instanceof FObject) {    
            ImageProcessor processor = new ImageProcessor();
        }
    }

    ExecutorService pool1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    synchronized (ImageHelper.getFilePaths()) {
        for (String file :ImageHelper.getFilePaths()) {
            pool1.execute(() -> {
                UploadFileAsAppUser.uploadFileAsBoxAppUser(file, boxLocation);
            });
        }
    }

    pool1.shutdown();
    if (pool1.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        pool1.shutdownNow();
    }
```

In snippet 1, I am prcessing as well as uploading images in multiple threads. In snippet 2, I am processing images in single thread and uploading them in multiple threds.

Comment: No, because [`awaitTermination(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) *"returns true if this executor terminated and **false if the timeout elapsed before termination**"*, so `pool1` will start after 10 seconds, even if `pool` still has active threads.

Comment: And if you flip `if` statement to `if (! awaitTermination)`, then: No, because [`shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--) *"**does not wait** for actively executing tasks to terminate"*.

Comment: But before awaitTermination, I'm calling pool.shutdown(). As per javadoc for shutdown(): 

"Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted."

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: And [`shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) also says *"This method **does not wait** for previously submitted tasks to complete execution"*, so what were you trying to say with that comment? --- The answer is still **No**, the code in snippet 1 does *not* guarantee that `pool1` will start only after the `pool` finished its execution. --- As for snippet 2, that seems to be the same, except you added some code that does nothing (creating then discarding objects without using them).

Answer (score 0):

A [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is usually useful if you want to wait for one or more task to complete before starting another.

Comment: If I take out first thread pool and keep only the second thread pool. Would it give a guarantee that pool will be executed only one the images are processed? Updated my question.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you have a collection of images, each of which needs to be processed and then uploaded?

Comment: I'm processing images first and adding them to a list. The processing code adds them to the list. This happens in a single thread. Now as soon as all the images are processed, I want to start uploading them in multiple threads.

Comment: Okay, but what is the overall intention? Does each image go through a processing stage and then get uploaded? I'm not sure why you need two different thread pools.

Comment: Yes, each image goes through the processing stage. Basically, the processing happens in the context of an application that we use. it's a third party application. There are some multithreading issues I'm facing in that application, therefore, I'm processing them in a single thread and adding all the file paths to a list. I want to upload them in multiple threads as the uploading happens irrespective to that third-party application.